# Drive Full Cassandra DSE

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise

I just recently had a drive fill up without my knowledge.  I added a new node, the rebuild went fine.  I then tried to run a cleanup but I get the common unable to write to disk due to space.  Whats the best method to fix this?  I do have replication, so I could just format the drive and rebuild, but not sure if its the best way.  Is there a way to manually delete the files by checking what exists on the new node?  Any ideas would be great, and I wont let it happen again!

Cluster Info :

Cassandra Version: 2.1.11.908

DataStax Enterprise Version: 4.8.2

Available Memory: 39283 MB

Number of CPU Cores: 16

Operating System: linux

We run multiple hard drives with the JBOD configuration.  So other drives have plenty, its just one drive on one node.

Update :  So I am still having problems.  I cleared up about 2.5TB of a 6.0TB drive and during the cleanup I am getting the following error :

java.io.IOException: disk full
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager.doCleanupOne(CompactionManager.java:778) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager.access$400(CompactionManager.java:88) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$5.execute(CompactionManager.java:406) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$2.call(CompactionManager.java:303) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72]

I need more space, and I am unsure I can clear some up without a cleanup.  But I cannot successfully run one.  I guess the only way out is to do nodetool rebuild after wiping the data from the drives and let it re-sync all the data back?

Comment: should be okay to move some sstables over from the filled up drive to one of the ones with capacity. https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/204226239-DSE-can-run-out-of-disk-space-using-JBOD-even-with-disks-available-

Comment: Excellent.  Time to start moving stuff around.  I noticed that there was a patch to this logic.  If I upgrade my nodes, does the content of the data need to be upgraded? Or did the file formats stay the same?

Comment: Major version upgrades require running sstableupgrade